# Get list of nodes starts by current node and ends with root

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2

I am working with Tree Panel in EXTJS 4.2 and i have some difficulties in passing the tree from current node (selected node) to the root.

In fact, when user click on a node, i want to get current node's parent and then the parent of the parent ... until I arrive to the Root of the Tree. so i will have a list of nodes starts from root and ends in the current node. 
Could you help me please by giving me any idea to get this list of nodes?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can use getPath to get the path from root to current node:

```
listeners: {
select: function( panel, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    var path = record.getPath('text','/');
}
```